# How to create a timeline in phpmyadmin using nanoseconds?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

I am currently trying to create a timeline in phpmyadmin from a mysql database, using java and jdbc. In the database I store IPs that I get from a pcap file, and I get the time I want from the packet (using `packet.getCaptureHeader().nanos()`). Every time an IP occurs I increment a counter. What I want is to create a timeline showing the progress of the sum of the counter of each IP. I tried something but I think I am in the wrong way. Any suggestions?

```
long timer=packet.getCaptureHeader().nanos();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/thesis?"
+ "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO  thesis.ICMP values (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1;");
preparedStatement.setString(1, xIP);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "ICMP");
preparedStatement.setInt(3, 1);
preparedStatement.setLong(4, timer);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I noticed that if I use DATE type variable, I can create easy timelines, but DATE doesn't support that kind of accuraccy. Please feel free to think out of the box, even suggest a new approach, I won't mind.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is a **PHP** application to manage your database, it has nothing to do with Java/JDBC. So how is PHPMyAdmin involved here?

Comment: After creating my database, I use phpmyadmin to create charts. I am not currently familiar on creating charts any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support nanosecond resolution. Since MySQL 5.6.4, there is support for [fractional seconds with microsecond precision](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html), but for further precision (or if you have an old MySQL version), you'll have to come up with something on your own.

Probably what I'd do in this particular case is store it as a date up to second resolution, then store the fractional portion of the second, converted to nanoseconds, as an unsigned INT (a signed integer would work, but you'd never want a negative value anyway). The downside is that searching and sorting becomes more difficult. [This person](http://www.marioberges.com/blog/2010/01/nano-second-timestamps-in-mysql/) is discussing storing the nanoseconds as a decimal, which I don't understand, but has some good thoughts on the issue aside from that. Another possibility is to use a BIGINT to store the number of nanoseconds since an epoch, but that only gives about 500 years of possible values. For your use, that may be fine, but is a limitation to keep in mind.

Comment: I don't think this will work, because I want to create a timeline after that. Do you have anything to suggest on graphs? I think a good solution could be using time as INT and just making that graph, but I'm afraid it won't be like a timeline.

Comment: Sorry, but you're going to have to compromise something because the functionality you're looking for just isn't there. You can either compromise on the nanosecond resolution and keep the phpMyAdmin charting feature, or get the resolution you're looking for but implement your own charts. About making the graph, you mentioned Java, so I also suggest checking TimeFlow or JARET Timebars.

Comment: So the best resolution that I can get is in seconds or something smaller? I wouldn't mind using milliseconds too.

Comment: You can get microsecond precision with MySQL 5.6.4 or newer.